# How can I bind each item in a List<Object> to a different Row and Column of a Grid in XAML?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have the following Grid in XAML:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfWords}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding xAxis}" Grid.Row="{Binding yAxis}" Text="{Binding wordDisplay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ItemsControl>
           
    </Grid>
```

The above does not work as expected, instead, It just shows all the items of the list in the first cell. How can I bind each word to a different cell in this Grid based off of the 'X' and 'Y' positions?

-- MainViewModel --

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Word> _word;
    public IEnumerable<Word> ListOfWords => _word;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _word = new ObservableCollection<Word>()
        {
            // xAxis, yAxis, wordDisplay
            new Word(0,0,"aaa"),
            new Word(0,3,"bbb"),
            new Word(6,8,"ccc"),
            new Word(1,7,"ddd"),
            new Word(3,3,"eee"),
            new Word(9,2,"fff"),
            new Word(6,1,"ggg"),
            new Word(0,5,"hhh")
        };
    }
}
```

The List will start off empty and as it gets populated, items will need to show up on the Grid.

Comment: Remove the Grid and use a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl.